# MySQL - displaying AVG on more than just one row

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

If I run a query that includes an `Aggregation function (AVG)`, is there any way I can get that to display on multiple rows? The query I need would be something like:

```
SELECT field1, field2, AVG(field2) FROM tMyTable;
```

The output I need would be something like:

```
field 1 | field 2 | AVG(field2)               
record1 | 1.17    | 1.19     
record2 | 1.21    | 1.19    
record3 | 1.18    | 1.19
```

As you can see, I need the average output to be displayed on each and every line. I appreciate that this may be/is an unorthodox approach, however that output format is needed for a charting app that I use.

If there are any methods available then I'd be grateful for your suggestions. Perhaps nesting a second lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT field1,field2,(SELECT AVG(field2) FROM Table) AS AvgFieldTwo
FROM Table
```

Comment: This can also be done as a join if your RDBMS sucks at subquery optimization in select statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT field1, field2, src.AvgField2
FROM MyTable
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT avg(field2) AvgField2
  FROM MyTable
) src
```